# Flutter create a select interests screen with dynamic sized bubbles

Tags: flutter

i'm pretty new to flutter therefore i'm searching for a library or tutorial to create such a screen:
[image: Select interests screen]

A library would be perfect

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?

Comment: kindly share the flutter package, if you achieve this bubble selection screen @Dominik

Answer (score 0):

There's now a library [bubbles_selection](https://pub.dev/packages/bubbles_selection) that might solve your problem.

It's in development though, so not sure if it is stable enough for you.